# Pass in dynamic widget object to QVariantAnimation valueChanged signal handler

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qvariantanimation

I'm trying to make an invalid animation tool. I have a button that when pressed, animates the background color of a field from red to the "normal" field color. This works great but now I want to pass in any **arbitrary** PyQt widget object (could be `QLineEdit`, `QComboBox`, and so on). Here's what my animation handler looks like:

[image]

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
def invalid_animation_handler(color: QtGui.QColor) -> None:
    field.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {QtGui.QColor(color).name()}")
```

Currently it requires that the `field` object be already named before calling the function to change the background. I would like to be able to dynamically pass in a `widget` and set the stylesheet on the fly by passing in a parameter, something like this:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
def invalid_animation_handler(widget, color: QtGui.QColor) -> None:
    widget.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {QtGui.QColor(color).name()}")
```

When I try to do this, the widget is able to be passed but the constant color change from `WARNING_COLOR` to `NORMAL_COLOR` doesn't work anymore. I also **do not want to put this into a class** since it has to be on-the-fly. My goal is being able to call a function to start the animation from anywhere instead of having to press the button. The desired goal is like this:

```
class VariantAnimation(QtCore.QVariantAnimation):
    """VariantAnimation: Implement method for QVariantAnimation to fix pure virtual method in PyQt5 -> PyQt4"""
    def updateCurrentValue(self, value):
        pass

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
def invalid_animation_handler(widget, color: QtGui.QColor) -> None:
    widget.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {QtGui.QColor(color).name()}")

def invalid_animation(widget):
    return VariantAnimation(startValue=ERROR_COLOR, endValue=NORMAL_COLOR, duration=ANIMATION_DURATION, valueChanged=lambda: invalid_animation_handler(widget))

def start_invalid_animation(animation_handler) -> None:
    if animation_handler.state() == QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Running:
        animation_handler.stop()
    animation_handler.start()

field = QtGui.QLineEdit()
field_animation_handler = invalid_animation(field)

# Goal is to make a generic handler to start the animation
start_invalid_animation(field_animation_handler)
```

Minimal working example

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class VariantAnimation(QtCore.QVariantAnimation):
    """VariantAnimation: Implement method for QVariantAnimation to fix pure virtual method in PyQt5 -> PyQt4"""
    def updateCurrentValue(self, value):
        pass

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
def invalid_animation_handler(color: QtGui.QColor) -> None:
    field.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {QtGui.QColor(color).name()}")

def start_field_invalid_animation() -> None:
    if field_invalid_animation.state() == QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Running:
        field_invalid_animation.stop()
    field_invalid_animation.start()
    
NORMAL_COLOR = QtGui.QColor(25,35,45)
SUCCESSFUL_COLOR = QtGui.QColor(95,186,125)
WARNING_COLOR = QtGui.QColor(251,188,5)
ERROR_COLOR = QtGui.QColor(247,131,128)
ANIMATION_DURATION = 1500

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    button = QtGui.QPushButton('Animate field background')
    button.clicked.connect(start_field_invalid_animation)
    field = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    field_invalid_animation = VariantAnimation(startValue=ERROR_COLOR, endValue=NORMAL_COLOR, duration=ANIMATION_DURATION, valueChanged=invalid_animation_handler)

    mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(button)
    layout.addWidget(field)
    window = QtGui.QWidget()
    window.setLayout(layout)
    mw.setCentralWidget(window)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You say: *I also do not want to put this into a class since it has to be on-the-fly*,  I do not understand your phrase, why would a class bring you problems?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm trying to make a generic handler to do invalid/valid animations. I already have tons of widgets created in my class like `self.button1`, `self.button2`, or `self.field1` so I just want to create the handler then call it whenever needed

Comment: I understand that *on-the-fly* implies that in the linked example you don't want "on_color_change" to be implemented in the GUI, am I correct?

Comment: That linked example has `QLineEdit` inherited as a class so to change the background it does `self.setStyleSheet()`. I'm trying to implement a technique where you can pass in arbitrary widget as a parameter to the "on_color_change" function. So then instead of doing `self`, it would be like `passed_widget_object.setStyleSheet()`

Comment: Yes, I don't want the "on_color_change" to be implemented in the class like that example. I'm looking for a generic function that could pass a widget object to change into that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand exactly why you do not want a class but IMO is the most suitable solution. The logic is to store the callable that allows to change the property and invoke it in updateCurrentValue.

Currently I don't have PyQt4 installed so I implemented the logic with PyQt5 but I don't think it is difficult to change the imports.

```py
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import partial
from typing import Callable

from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractAnimation, QObject, QVariant, QVariantAnimation
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
)


@dataclass
class VariantAnimation(QVariantAnimation):
    widget: QWidget
    callback: Callable[[QWidget, QVariant], None]
    start_value: QVariant
    end_value: QVariant
    duration: int
    parent: QObject = None

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setStartValue(self.start_value)
        self.setEndValue(self.end_value)
        self.setDuration(self.duration)
        self.setParent(self.parent)

    def updateCurrentValue(self, value):
        if isinstance(self.widget, QWidget) and callable(self.callback):
            self.callback(self.widget, value)


def invalid_animation_handler(widget: QWidget, color: QColor) -> None:
    widget.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {QColor(color).name()}")


def start_field_invalid_animation(animation: QAbstractAnimation) -> None:
    if animation.state() == QAbstractAnimation.Running:
        animation.stop()
    animation.start()


NORMAL_COLOR = QColor(25, 35, 45)
SUCCESSFUL_COLOR = QColor(95, 186, 125)
WARNING_COLOR = QColor(251, 188, 5)
ERROR_COLOR = QColor(247, 131, 128)
ANIMATION_DURATION = 1500

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    button = QPushButton("Animate field background")

    field = QLineEdit()
    animation = VariantAnimation(
        widget=field,
        callback=invalid_animation_handler,
        start_value=ERROR_COLOR,
        end_value=NORMAL_COLOR,
        duration=ANIMATION_DURATION,
    )

    button.clicked.connect(partial(start_field_invalid_animation, animation))

    mw = QMainWindow()
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(button)
    layout.addWidget(field)
    window = QWidget()
    window.setLayout(layout)
    mw.setCentralWidget(window)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```